# How to change standardized predicted values of neural network into un standard values?

Tags: r, nnet

I used nnet package in R to train the neural network and make prediction. At first, because the output values were large, i used the formula (x-xmin)/(xmax-xmin) to standardize them in range of 0 to 1. After training the network, i predicted the output values. The result is a range of data in range of 0 and 1.

How can i un standardize the predicted values to have predicted values of the first unit?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your formula to standardize, I'd suggest to use the available function `scale` (see [here](http://rgm.ogalab.net/RGM/R_rdfile?f=base/man/scale.Rd&d=R_rel)).

That way, you'll be able to use `unscale` (see [here](http://rgm.ogalab.net/RGM/R_rdfile?f=DMwR/man/unscale.Rd&d=R_CC)).

If you've used that formula because it has significance for what you are doing, you could follow a procedure as described in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104069/question-about-normalize-scale-data-before-using-neuralnet) of stats.stackexchange.com. (Basically, you have always to store the `center` and `scale` you are using to standardize, so that you can apply them in the inverse way).